# Ora2pg ALLOW and EXCLUDE directive not working

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, database-migration, ora2pg

I am using **ora2pg** tool for database migration(oracle to PostgreSQL). I have to exclude some object from export, For that i have made changes accordingly in ora2pg config file(add comma separate list in exclude directive).
But when i execute this ora2pg config file it will export all object for me(Not exclude object that i added in exclude directive).
Other directives working fine. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Show use your config file

Comment: I have set Exclude directive Like - #EXCLUDE USER_RELEASE_LOGIN, NODE_TABLE

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, for example, for exclude tables:

ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf -t TABLE -e tables_excludes -o junotele.sql -b schema/tables/

Answer (score 0):

You must not use comma  to separate your tables. Use blanks instead:

```
EXCLUDE TABLE1 TABLE2 TABLE3
```

will exclude these tables (TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3) from export.

See: https://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html#Limiting-objects-to-export